# which Operation will perform first in onStart or onCreate in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

I want to perform one data base Operation once.  **I want to do this when My Activity is Visible.**  Where shall I puty my LoadDatabase() function

```
    LoadDatabase();
```

this is my  oncreate of activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.retrospectscan); 

    }
```

this is my onStart

```
@Override 
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}
```

Where Shall I put my LoadDatabase Code ? So that It will operated **only if activity is fully Visible.**

If Any other Approach is there please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The complete activity lifecycle is here:

[image]

Though loading from database may be lengthy task , you can try doing it in `AsyncTask` or in `onStart`.

You can also use it on `onResume`. This depends on your application use.

Answer (score 0):

user2737044

use **Application** context and load your database in application context create().

2nd thing is that, In activity onCreate() call first then it will call onstart().

Comment: bhai  If you will see the Activity flow.First oncreate then onStart